# That mightn't/can't/mustn't be true.The director is quite talented

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> That mightn't/can't/mustn't be true.The director is quite talented.

MyApproach:

I am confused between mightn't and can't because:

Mightn't:mightn't  also be used to show possibility.

can't:can  is also used to show possibility that it can't be true.

Comment: Actually "can't" states the **im**possibility that it's true rather than a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

*That **might** be true* and *That **might** not be true* speak to possibility: it is *possible* that it is true or false, but not certain.

*That **must** be true* and *That **must** not be true* speak to certainty: I am *certain* that it is true or false.

*Can* is a little tricky.

- It is fairly common in the negative, *That **can't** be true*, and it speaks to certainty with the same sense as *That **must not** be true.*
- It is less common in the positive, *That **can** be true*. It usually employed in a contrastive context (for instance, to contradict somebody's assertion that something *can't* be true), and it speaks to possibility, with the same sense as *That **may** be true*.

Comment: In, for example, [*Jesus **might** be the son of God, but could he microwave a burrito so hot that even he could not eat it?*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060822083228AAq1Mvk), I don't really think there's any implication of the speaker casting doubt on Jesus's parentage (that would require ***could*** rather than ***might***). In such contexts, ***might*** usually implies a "contrastive context" *(X **might [well]** be true = X **is** true, **but** this fact **might** not be compatible with some other fact also thought to be true)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's getting into a different rhetorical **use** of possibility, a *concessive*; it concedes the possibility, but dismisses its relevance.

Comment: You might be more *au fait* with the terminology than me, but I refuse to admit either (a) - that I imply even the faintest possibility that you might *not* be, or (b) - that such "different rhetorical uses" aren't potentially relevant to OP's question. I might also add that the contraction ***mightn't*** sounds extremely *British* to me (besides being dated & starchy), but I can't find any evidence to support that position in Google Books (which now insists on converting it to ***might not*** anyway). Any thoughts?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's hard to know when to stop when discussing modals! I'm not sure what the boundaries are on OP's Q, so I kept it narrow. By the way, I think I'd use *may* and *can* in your Jesus quote; I don't know if that's evidence of the Atlantic divide or just my idiolect. I quite agree that *mightn't* is Britisher, dateder, and uppercrustier.

Comment: @StoneyB I like your views but I am not able differentiate between mightn't and can't.What will be the Ans also?

Comment: @Jalaj Chawla: Don't use contracted negated ***mightn't*** at all (it's a rather "unusual" form today). Some people still think only *current* possibilities ***may*** be true, whereas things in the *past* ***might*** have been true, but [as you can read here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/may-or-might), that's now a fading distinction, so you can probably forget about it. And remember that *X **might not** be true* means there's at least a *possibility* that X is false, but if you say *X **can not / cannot / can't** be true* you're asserting that X *must* be false.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And now i am confused between mustn't and cantn't.

Comment: @Jalaj Chawla: *You **mustn't** do that* always means you're ***not allowed*** to do it. Sometimes, *You **can't** do it* carries that sense, but normally it means you ***don't have the ability*** (whether it's "permitted" or not isn't relevant).

Comment: @JalajChawla There are no simple formulas. The meaning of each of the modal verbs changes greatly in different contexts. *Must*, for instance: *You mustn't do that* means you're forbidden to do that, but *He mustn't do that* usually means "We need to prevent him from doing that*, while *He mustn't have done that* means *It seems to me impossible that he did that*.